# mysql replication : utilizing insert delayed

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a batch database that i would like to replicate to a reporting database but the queries that run on the reporting database might be very long (execution time wise) to the point where they can cause a deadlock (this is happening now because both batch and reporting applications are using the same DB) , i thought of changing the table's engines in the reporting database (the once that are replicated from batch) to mysiam and then somehow replicate with insert delayed and thus simulating somehow a "persist eventually" mechanism in mysql and as a result prioritize the reporting reads (they do allot of temp table creations) .
can this be done on the replication client alone (i.e. : not touching the master queries , the batch does not insert with insert delayed)  ? and is this a good solution ?
thanks

Comment: Are you currently replicating from the 'batch' database to the 'reporting' database?

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore any deadlock queries on your slave.  The only queries that would affect your replication would be insert/update queries.  A long-running SELECT query would only hog resources.